# How to sticky widget inside frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, grid

I tried to sticky Entry widgets to right (by `sticky='e'`) and labels to left, but entry widgets are "sticky" to left.

[image]

Could you help me? Maybe i should do extrack the widgets out of frames to single main frame?

My code:

```py
class LabeledEntry(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,
                 master: Union[tk.Misc, None] = None,
                 label_text='', default: str = '') -> None:
        super().__init__(master,
                         width=250,
                         height=30,
                         border=3,
                         borderwidth=2,
                         highlightthickness=2,
                         highlightbackground='blue')
        self.grid_propagate(False)
        self._label = tk.Label(self,
                               text=label_text)
        self._label.grid(row=0,
                         column=0)
        self._entry = tk.Entry(self,
                               width=17)
        self._entry.grid(row=0,
                         column=1,
                         sticky='e')
        if default:
            self._entry.insert(0, default)
```

```py
class ConfigurationFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master) -> None:
        super().__init__(master)

        # TODO rozciagnac na cala szerokosc
        self.dchg_current = LabeledEntry(self, "x")
        self.dchg_current.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW", columnspan=2)
        self.cutoff_volt = LabeledEntry(self, "C                  X")
        self.cutoff_volt.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NESW", columnspan=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the entry box to the right, you need to make column 1 of the frame to occupy all the available horizontal space using `self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`:

```py
class LabeledEntry(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,
                 master: Union[tk.Misc, None] = None,
                 label_text='', default: str = '') -> None:
        super().__init__(master,
                         width=250,
                         height=30,
                         border=3,
                         borderwidth=2,
                         highlightthickness=2,
                         highlightbackground='blue')
        self.grid_propagate(False)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        ...
```

Result:

[image]

---

Note that it is easier when using `pack()` instead of `grid()`:

```py
class LabeledEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,
                 master: Union[tk.Misc, None] = None,
                 label_text='', default: str = '') -> None:
        super().__init__(master,
                         width=250,
                         height=30,
                         border=3,
                         borderwidth=2,
                         highlightthickness=2,
                         highlightbackground='blue')
        self.pack_propagate(False)
        self._label = tk.Label(self, text=label_text)
        self._label.pack(side="left")

        self._entry = tk.Entry(self, width=17)
        self._entry.pack(side="right")

        if default:
            self._entry.insert(0, default)
```

Comment: It's work. Thank you! Do you know why `.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` works as i want, but `.columnconfigure((1, 2), weight=1)` not?